# Why is it that when I use startForeground in a service the Kotlin object's initialization is not called when the app is started for a second time?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, viewmodel, foreground-service

I have an app where I start a **service in the foreground** from an activity. Once I’m done using the app I need to be able to destroy the service when the app is killed (swipe up).
To accomplish this, I used a **Kotlin object/singleton** as it seems to be the simplest way **to communicate between the service and the viewmodel** where I can use the `onCleared` method to change the state that I will use to destroy the service.  Inside the service I use a **coroutine** to check if the app is still alive every second. **The state of the app is stored in the object. If the app is not alive, I destroy the service.**
The problem I’m having is that the object is initialized correctly the first time I open the app, but when I kill it and start it again (2nd time), the initialization of the object never happens.
This is easy to see as the notification is closed immediately upon starting the app, this is because the state `isAlive` is `false`, and should be `true` if the object was initialized.
If I kill the app one more time and start it again (3rd time), this time the initialization is correctly done. This behavior is not random.

What I’ve found out is that if I don’t call the `startForeground` method (that I need), the object is correctly initialized every time without exception, so I suppose there is something that changes the behavior of the system when `startForeground` is called.

I’ve tested it with the emulator and with a physical device with the same result.

I attach the full code, so you can replicate the behavior easily.

Thank you very much in advance!

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.appwithsingletontest

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.viewModels

const val notificationChannelID = "channel_01"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        createNotificationChannel() //Should be called as soon as the app starts.
        val vm: ActivityViewModel by viewModels()
        vm.dummy = true //Used to initialize the ViewModel (Lazy initialization).
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val intentService = Intent(this, MainService::class.java)

        startService(intentService)
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
            val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(notificationChannelID, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
}
```

**MainService.kt**

```
package com.example.appwithsingletontest

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class MainService : Service() {

    private val job = SupervisorJob()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

    private val ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
    private lateinit var notification : Notification

    override fun onCreate() {

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
            }

        notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannelID)
            .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_title))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setNotificationSilent()
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)

    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val isAppAlive = DataBridge.appIsAlive()

        scope.launch {
            while(true){
                delay(1000)
                if(!DataBridge.appIsAlive()) {
                    stopForeground(true)
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        job.cancel()
        Log.i("AWST MainService", "####### THE END #######.")
    }
}
```

**ActivityViewModel.kt**

```
package com.example.appwithsingletontest

import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class ActivityViewModel : ViewModel(){

    var dummy = false

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        DataBridge.appWasKilled()
    }
}
```

**DataBridge.kt**

```
package com.example.appwithsingletontest

import android.util.Log

object DataBridge {

    init { Log.i("AWST DataBridge", "Initialization !!!!!!!!") }

    private var isAlive = true

    fun appIsAlive(): Boolean {
        Log.i("AWST DataBridge", "Inside method appIsAlive(). The value is: $isAlive")
        return isAlive
    }

    fun appWasKilled(){ isAlive = false }

}
```

Comment: If you do have a foreground service your app is considered active so even if you swipe it away from recents its process is not being killed and `DataBridge` object persists. If you **don't** have a foreground service system immediately terminates your apps process.

Comment: @Pawel, thanks for the comment, but I already knew that. I do destroy the service once there is a change in the state of `isAlive` through `DataBridge.appWasKilled()`, that is called from `onCleared` in the `ActivityViewModel`, when the app is swiped away.

Comment: If your service was alive while swiping away task from recents it will keep your app process alive, stopping service afterwards will not cause process to be terminated. Just open logcat and see logs from `system_process`, it should log when process is being killed.

Comment: @Pawel you were and are right! I missed the word **process** in your first comment. **The key here is that the process continues to be alive even though the app is swiped away and the service is stopped properly.** Now I will need to investigate the relation between a service and a process to know exactly why this is happening. To test the efficacy of killing the process I’ve added `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` in the `onDestroy` method of the service and it behaves as expected. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Pawel, if you want to answer the question explaining the details of why this is happening I will vote it as the correct one. You deserve the credit! Thanks again!